# Multidimensional array makes Xcode6 crash

Tags: swift, xcode6

I have an application which retrieves a JSON file. Here you are a piece of my code:

**Array definition**

```
var photos: NSArray = []
```

**How I populate the array:**

```
ezJson().createRequest("http://myapiurl/load", type: "GET", params: nil, completion: {(returnedObject : AnyObject?, error : NSError?)in
            if returnedObject{

                self.photos = returnedObject as NSArray
                self.tableView.reloadData()

            }
        })
```

**println(self.photos)**

```
{
        created =         {
            date = "2014-06-13 18:35:46";
            timezone = "Europe/Madrid";
            "timezone_type" = 3;
        };
        description = description1;
        id = 3;
        name = 539b286277617;
    },
        {
        created =         {
            date = "2014-06-13 18:38:38";
            timezone = "Europe/Madrid";
            "timezone_type" = 3;
        };
        description = description2;
        id = 4;
        name = 539b290ed8577;
    }
```

**println(self.photos[0])**

```
{
    created =     {
        date = "2014-06-13 18:35:46";
        timezone = "Europe/Madrid";
        "timezone_type" = 3;
    };
    description = description1;
    id = 3;
    name = 539b286277617;
}
```

The problem is, I don't know how to get a particular item. I've tried:

```
println(self.photos[0]) // it works

println(self.photos[0]["name"] // Xcode crash "Command /Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift failed with exit code 254"

println(self.photos[0].name) // returns nil
```

How can I access to the name parameter ?

Comment: What does `println(self.photos[0]` print? And how do you populate your array with the JSON data?

Comment: What is the class of self.photos[0] ?

Comment: Regarding Xcode crash - it's a) Xcode, b) _beta_. It crashes every I type `[1, [2, 3]][1][1]` in playground, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are casting a `String` to `NSArray`. This won't give you the effect that you want.

First of all, if you want to acces your elements by name, you want an `NSDictionary`.
Then it propably still won't work, as there is no implicit conversion between the types so you will have to either parse it yourself or use some JSON library.

Last : your JSON is incorrect.

Comment: thanks, my json was incorrect and I was able to get this with JSONKit library.